# Monotouch: Adding .a resource , gcc error

Tags: c++, gcc, xamarin.ios, static-libraries, admob

Using this project: https://github.com/dalexsoto/Monotouch-AdMob-Bindings

I am adding the AdMob .a to my MonoTouch app. I'm not sure that these compile errors mean, though I guess the bindings in the MonoTouch dll are not correct?:

**Compile Flags:**

> -v -v -v -gcc_flags "-framework AudioToolbox -L${ProjectDir}
>   -lGoogleAdMobAds -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libGoogleAdMobAds.a"

**Resulting error:**

```
Undefined symbols:
  "__Unwind_Resume", referenced from:
      -[GADIdentifierUtilities locale] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADIdentifierUtilities.o)
      -[GADIdentifierUtilities iTunesMetadata] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADIdentifierUtilities.o)
      -[GADOpener openNotification:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADOpener.o)
      -[GADNotification initWithNotificationURL:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADNotification.o)
      -[GADWebView initWithFrame:] in libGoogleAdMobAds.a(GADWebView.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding **--cxx** if often enough but, since it does not work, you might want to try being more specific and also add **-lgcc_s** - this time inside the **gcc_flags**, so using something like:

**-v -v -v -cxx -gcc_flags="-lgcc_s ..."**

in your 'extra mtouch arguments'.

Answer (score 0):

You have to instruct mtouch to use the g++ compiler. You do this by adding the "-cxx" argument in your mtouch args, eg: "-v -v -v -cxx - gcc_flags...".

Comment: This is documented in http://ios.xamarin.com/Documentation/Linking_Native_Libraries but I guess the main issue it mapping "__Unwind_Resume" to C++

Comment: -cxx didn't fix the problem, I still get a __Unwind_Resume error